# How can I add multiple datasets into my dropdown menu and keep it as dynamic as it is right now?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I really need your help. I currently build a dropdown menu that shows different line graphs. However, I do not know how I Can add additional datasets into my code without losing the dynamics. I am pretty sure that it is pretty obvious. I am just new to JS. Is it maybe possible to create some headings or sth like that?In the following you can see my code:

```js
let let_25 = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78];
let let_50 = [28, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 62, 66, 70, 78];
let let_10_90 = [40, 65, 63, 64, 72, 79, 83, 87, 100, 108];
let let_med = [30, 40, 45, 50, 56, 60, 66, 73, 78, 85];
let let_25_75 = [35, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94];
let let_10 = [25, 30, 36, 39, 45, 49, 53, 56, 60, 68];

const decimals = 0;

let myData = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9+"],
  datasets: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      borderWith: 3,
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      fill: 4,
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      data: let_25,
      tension: .4,
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      radius: 3,
      pointStyle: "circle",
      hitRadius: 1,
      hoverRadius: 4,
      hoverBorderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      borderWith: 3,
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderDash: [],
      fill: '0',
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      data: let_10,
    }, {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: 0,
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: '#645bff',
      borderDash: [],
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      borderWith: 3,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      data: let_25_75,
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: 2,
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderDash: [],
      borderWith: 3,
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderColor: '#c4c1ff',
      data: let_10_90,
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      radius: 3,
      lineWidth: 1,
      borderWidth: 2,
      hitRadius: 1,
      hoverRadius: 4,
      hoverBorderWidth: 1,
      pointStyle: 'circle',
      pointborderColor: "#0d0e25",
      fill: false,
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: '#0d0e25',
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderColor: '#0d0e25',
      borderColor: '#0d0e25',
      data: let_med,
      tension: .4,
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      capBezierPoints: true,
    }
  ]
};

var myChart;

function updateChartType() {
  if (myChart) {
    myChart.destroy();
  }
  myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
    type: document.getElementById("chartType").value,
    data: myData,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
            if (label) {
              label += ': ';
            }
            if (label === "25th - 75th Percentile: ") {
              label = "75th Percentile: "
            }
            if (label === "10th - 90th Percentile: ") {
              label = "90th Percentile: "
            }
            label += tooltipItem.yLabel
            return label;

          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          id: 'a',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Salary',
            fontSize: 20
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 20,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              return '$' + value.toFixed(decimals)
            }
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stepSize: 20,

          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Years of relevant experience',
            fontSize: 20
          }
        }]
      },
      legend: {
        onClick: (e) => e.stopPropagation(),
        display: true,
        labels: {
          filter: item => !['25th Percentile', '10th Percentile'].includes(item.text)
        }
      },
    }
  })
};

updateChartType();
```

```html
<script>
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"
  "https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js?cb=%2Fr20100101"
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="label">Chart Type</h5>
<select name="chartType" id="chartType" onchange="updateChartType()">
  <option value="line">Backend Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Frontend Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Fullstack Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Mobile Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Engineering Management</option>
  <option value="line">DevOps & Infrastructure</option>
  <option value="line">Engineering Management</option>
  <option value="line">Data Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Data Analysis & BI</option>
  <option value="line">Data Scientist</option>
  <option value="line">QA & Testing Engineer</option>
  <option value="line">Security Engineer</option>
</select>

<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; width:85vw">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First update your `myData` variable where `newDataset` contains your additional data:

```
myChart.config.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
```

Then call `update()` method to update your chart:

```
myChart.update();
```

Comment: I do not really see what you mean...where do I add a new dataset..can you make an example in my code